# Unable to display figures using imshow in cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I used OpenCV to display the figure but got an error: Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = cv2.imread('xyz.jpg', -1)
cv2.imshow('img', a)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:364: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

The figure can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_8BCFgHoWb46RVZWLu5sl7mgrdEr48yH).

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: is .gif or .jpg?

Comment: It is a jpg file.

Comment: When I use the link of your image to download it tells me that the resource is not available to download by drive, then I want to download it manually by right clicking and select the option to download image and when it finishes downloading I get a gif image.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is a gif file with one frame.

Comment: Can gif file be read by cv2?

Comment: Not directly: http://answers.opencv.org/question/72134/cv2imread-cannot-read-gifs/, a possible solution is to use other libraries to convert the .gif to another type of image supported by opencv

Comment: Thanks. Can cv2 detect the file type?

Comment: The does not detect, opencv verifies if the format of the image matches one that has been supported since the formats do not provide raw data since they are compressed.

Comment: I found that `imghdr` can detect the file type: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/imghdr.html